# iOS Cydia THEOS, make install, Could not find deb package

Tags: ios, debian, theos, deb, cydia

I followed the instructions here and it happens in both tweak and app:

http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Setup#Creating_a_Project

But I don't see any .deb files

```
RoverMR-2:testapp rover$ find . -name "deb"
```

Here are several relevant command output logs: 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/42b4a086d6b7ee792b08

I just see this in packages:

RoverMR-2:testapp rover$ ls -la .theos/packages/
total 8
    drwxr-xr-x 3 rover staff 102 Apr 30 11:12 .
    drwxr-xr-x 4 rover staff 136 Apr 30 11:12 ..
    -rw-r--r-- 1 rover staff 1 Apr 30 11:12 com.mysite.testapp-0.0.1

```
RoverMR-2:testapp rover$ make package
```

/Users/rover/Documents/Dev/Cydia/Theos/apps/testapp/theos/makefiles/targets/Darwin/iphone.mk:41: Deploying to iOS 3.0 while building for 6.0 will generate armv7-only binaries.

```
Making all for application testapp...
Copying resource directories into the application wrapper...
Compiling main.m...
Compiling testappApplication.mm...
Compiling RootViewController.mm...
Linking application testapp...
Stripping testapp...
Signing testapp...
Making stage for application testapp...
RoverMR-2:testapp rover$ 
RoverMR-2:testapp rover$ ls
Makefile RootViewController.h _ main.m testappApplication.mm
Resources RootViewController.mm control obj theos
RoverMR-2:testapp rover$
```

the error:

```
RoverMR-2:testapp rover$ make install    
    /Users/rover/Documents/Dev/Cydia/Theos/tweaks/testtweak/theos/makefiles/targets/Darwin/iphone.mk:41: Deploying to iOS 3.0 while building for 6.0 will generate armv7-only binaries.
    Could not find "./com.yourcompany.testtweak_0.0.1-10_iphoneos-arm.deb" to install. Aborting.
```

I posted an issue about this https://github.com/DHowett/theos/issues/120

Answer (score -1):

Type `make package install` all at once in the tweak's directory.